# The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "extranet\Everyone", but the current user is ""

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

The following error is being logged "LoginAntiforgeryHandleErrorAttribute bypass: The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "extranet\Everyone", but the current user is ""." when trying to use the AntiForgery token attribute is being used.

The post method work fine if the attribute is removed above the post method.